# Finding All Time Highest Voted Questions by tag

Tags: feature-request, new-nav

In the old navigation model, to see top questions in a particular tag you just

1. Click the Tag
2. Go to the *Votes* tab
3. *Profit*

With the new model, it took me a little while to find out how to get the same information.

1. Click the Tag
2. Go to *Popular* tab
3. Filter *Show* by *All Time*
4. Filter *Sort* by *Votes*
5. *Profit*

It's not at all intuitive coming from the old navigation. Is this on purpose to garner more attention to the unanswered or new questions?

I often go through a tag's top questions when I'm looking to learn something new or if I can't figure out what key words to use in a search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's *much* easier to do this from search:

`[php] is:question`

[Produces this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+is%3Aquestion), which lets you quickly drill into votes. As far as I know, the new navigation isn't going to affect the UI you see for search (and if it did, easy sorting based on score / etc would just get easier).

Using [more advanced modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) lets you drill in even more efficiently, my example was very simple.

Part of the goal, in conjunction with other initiatives is to surface things that would likely interest you, which you might not see otherwise. The nav is an effort into making it *much* easier to do it on your own. Getting stuff in front of you where there's theoretically something there for you to do is pretty important.

It's not fully baked yet, as far as I know, but 'mining' into stuff is generally better done through search, since you have *many* more options.

Comment: Sorting tag questions by votes is hardly "data mining", it's rather trivial action, or at least should be, so I really expect it to be available via the "quick navigation" like it is these days. I opted out from the alpha testing because my primary use of MSE is searching for existing things by tags, and it was totally broken.